# Ошибка в свойствах и функциях

Tags: php

Со стороны сервера я делаю такую штуку:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array("SELECT img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type FROM pokemon WHERE id_pok = '".$_GET['startpoke']."'")  or die('Error:'.mysql_error());
```

и мне выбивает такую ошибку:

*Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:xampphtdocsstyleregister.php*

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.

Comment: >C:xampphtdocsstyleregister.php

это наш мего редактор напортачил, или вы с путями что то напутали?

Comment: Prikol вы делаетет ежедневно одни и те же ошибки!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала sql нужно выполнить(execute) а потом вытаскивать из него результат выборки, о чем вам и говорится в сообщении об ошибке..

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT img,name,life,atk,def,exp,type FROM pokemon WHERE id_pok = '".$_GET['startpoke']."'")  or die('Error:'.mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  print_r($row);
}
```